# how to link shared library against other shared library in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, shared

My application dynamically loads `liba.so` (with `dlopen`).
`liba.so` uses `libb.so` so I want to link `liba.so` against `libb.so`. 
How to do this in Linux?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you build `liba.so` yourself, you need to link it with `-l` option

```
gcc -o liba.so liba.o -L/libb/path -lb
```

If you don't have `liba` sources, perhaps you could create `libawrapper.so` linked against `liba` and `libb` and to load dynamically this library

```
gcc -o libawrap.so -L/liba/ -L/libb/ -la -lb
```